# Py2app PyQt4 Symbol not found in _qt.so

Tags: python, macos, pyqt4, py2app

I'm building an OSX Sierra App with Py2app. The build finishes without any problems and on the build PC the app launches without any problem. When I port it to a target system (same osx version), the program won't run. It says `ImportError: dlopen(...PyQt4/_qt.so) Symbol not found`.

One might guess something is missing, but I don't know anymore where to look. QDataStream seems to be part of QtCore, which is definitely included. The full error it produces is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Work/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 81, in <module>
    _run()
  File "/Users/Work/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 66, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, 'exec'), globals(), globals())
  File "/Users/Work/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/MyApp.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
  File "PyQt4/QtGui.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "PyQt4/QtGui.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "PyQt4/_qt.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "PyQt4/_qt.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Work/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/PyQt4/_qt.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN11QDataStreamC1EP10QByteArrayi
  Referenced from: /Users/Work/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore
 in /Users/Work/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui
2017-04-21 17:46:55.983 MyApp[44290:6824335] MyApp Error
```

I included sip in the setup.py to be sure. I also tried with just `'PyQt4', 'paramiko'` in the includes, but that didn't help either. setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['/Users/username/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp.py']
DATA_FILES = ['/Users/username/Desktop/MyApp/icons']
OPTIONS = {'includes': ['sip', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'PyQt4.Qt', 'PyQt4.QtGui', 'paramiko'],
           'excludes': ['PyQt4.QtDesigner', 'PyQt4.QtNetwork', 'PyQt4.QtOpenGL', 'PyQt4.QtScript', 'PyQt4.QtSql', 'PyQt4.QtTest', 'PyQt4.QtWebKit', 'PyQt4.QtXml', 'PyQt4.phonon'],
           'iconfile':'/Users/username/Desktop/MyApp/icons/icon.icns'}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```